# Uninstalled Skyrim and redownloaded it to find all items in tundra homestead gone

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing Skyrim and uninstalled the game and installed it back - well, everything is working but I went into the Tundra homestead that I owned and had all my items stored in and EVERYTHING is gone.  Did I lose everything or is there any hope of getting them back :(

Comment: Are you missing mods?